# CSS styles doesn't apply when using ngClass

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-class

I have a problem with dynamically CSS updating. This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="ListItems">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/style.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="ListController as list">
    <h1>To-do list</h1>

    <div id="main">
        <article ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-class="{{item.IsCompleted ? 'completed' : 'uncompleted'}}">
            <p>{{item.Description}}</p>
            <footer>
                <small>
                    Is completed: <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{item.IsCompleted}}" ng-click="complete($index)" />
                </small>
            </footer>
        </article>
    </div>

    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And now I want to apply the following css styles if item is completed:

```
.completed {
    background-color: red;
}
```

But nothing happened.

Comment: look at F12 debugger and look a tstyles being applied or not. you also see the reason

Comment: My `article` got `completed` class, but I didn't see any visible changes on the page.

Comment: Invalid syntax for `ng-class`.

Comment: @JosephKatzman no need to use `{{}}` inside `ng-class`, just have an expression or JSON there as @lin answer

Comment: @PankajParkar cheers m8 =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the correct `ng-class` syntax and ensure that `.completed` CSS class is available due to your CSS declarations. Here is a simple working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1y4gLcnb/1/) which will help you. Compare it with your solution. Please take a look at the [ng-class documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) of AngularJS.

```
<article ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" 
         ng-class="{'completed': item.IsCompleted, 'uncompleted': !item.IsCompleted}">
    <p>{{item.Description}}</p>
    <footer>
        <small>
            Is completed: 
            <input type="checkbox" 
                   ng-checked="{{item.IsCompleted}}" 
                   ng-click="complete($index)" />
        </small>
    </footer>
</article>
```

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. You are right, but how it possible? Why my example doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the ng-class syntax. make it simple:

```
<article ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-class="{'completed': item.IsCompleted}">
```